# How to install Tomcat 7 and MySQL on AWS EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, tomcat, amazon-web-services

**My Question**

I am running a AWS EC2 micro instance with Amazon Linux. Now I want to install `Tomcat 7` and `MySQL` and `MySQL Workbench`on this instance. I also want to copy my Java Servlets on Netbeans on my PC to Tomcat 7 on AWS?

I have a Windows 7 running on my PC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html

It's a description of Amazon Linux.

Basically you install software via the packagemanager yum.

Copying files to a remote server can be done with SCP.